# Passing data from column

Tags: vba

I have userform with three fields (COMNAME; COMCOMPANY; TXTVALUE) I tried to pass value from column F to TXTVALUE (textbox) when COMNAME and COMCOMPANY (combo boxes) values are matched row values in columns C and D.

```
Dim var1 As Integer
Dim var2 As Integer

With Application.WorksheetFunction

var1 = .Match(Me.COMCOMPANY.Value, sheet.range("C7:C10"), 0)
var2 = .Match(Me.COMNAME.Value, sheet.range("D7:D10"), 0)

TXTVALUE.Value = .Index(sheet.range("F7:F10"), var1, var2)

End With
```

Table looks like this

```
column C |column D |Column F
PA       |   CT    | 750
RS       |   HA    | 550
PA       |   CS    | 358
```

When i execute this macro the result in txtvalue is good if is select PA (COMCOMPANY) and CT (COMNAME) - the TXTVALUE is 750 but when I select PA (COMCOMPany) and CS (COMNAME) - the macro return error "Unable to get index property of WorksheetFunction Class".

How to make this code or code like this to work. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have some confusion as to how the index function (and possibly the match function) works.

The match function works like this:

`MATCH(x, rng, intExact)`

means to find the FIRST value `x` in the range `rng` and the `intExact` parameter is defining whether you want the first value less than, exactly equal to, or more than the value `x`.  In your case `intExact` = 0 and you are searching for values exactly equal.  This function will return the row number that the first match is found, beginning with the top of the range.

Assuming that you have displayed cells `D6:F9` in your case var1 will return 1 for `PA`.  Var2 will return 1 for `CT` and 3 for `CS`.  There is no relation between the two variables.  Var1 is searching in the `D` column for your input, and Var2 is searching in the `F` column for your second input.

The `INDEX` function works like this:

`INDEX(rng, lngRow, lngCol)`

means to go in the `rng` and get the specified row, `lngrow` and column `lngcol` starting from the upper left part of the range.  In your first case, you select row 1 and column 1 in range `F7:F10`, which happens to be `750`.  It is a coincidence that this works, because the match in the E column happens to be in the first row.

In your second case, you try to select the value in row 1 and column 3, but there is only 1 column in your range, so you get an error.

You need to combine this with a lookup column.

```
column C |column D |Column F | Column Z
PA       |   CT    | 750     |  PACT
RS       |   HA    | 550     |  RSHA
PA       |   CS    | 358     |  PACS
```

And use the function:

```
Var1 = .Match(Me.COMCOMPANY.Value & Me.COMNAME.Value, _ 
                  sheet.range("Z7:Z10"), 0)

TXTVALUE.Value = .Index(sheet.range("F7:F10"), var1)
```

You can omit the column parameter of the Index function.

If you are unsure what is happening, it is best to step through the code, noting what the variables are.  In the case of the `WorksheetFunction` function you can then actually put the function in a cell and supply the values that the variables are to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.Match` function to avoid possible errors being thrown and handle them in the returned variable of `Variant` type

```
Dim var1 As Variant
Dim var2 As Variant

With Application
    var1 = .Match(Me.COMCOMPANY.Value, sheet.range("C7:C10"), 0)
    If Not IsError(var1) Then
       var2 = .Match(Me.COMNAME.Value, sheet.range("D7:D10"), 0)
       If Not IsError(var2) And var1 = var2 Then Me.TXTVALUE.Value = sheet.range("F7:F10").Rows(var1)
    End If
End With
```